# When not to partition a table (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, partitioning, bigdata

In MySQL (5.5+), 
for large tables (500,000,000 rows and up), 
that you access (read & write) always by specifying the primary key, 
are there times when **partitioning** (by the primary key) will **not improve performance**?

In particular, when each row is very thin (3 int columns).

Reason to ask:
For a table with heavy content (multiple varchar/text columns) I've seen a good improvement but in a similar case for thin rows (3 int columns) I think I'm seeing worse performance then without partitions.
[both use 100 partitions based on primary key(int)]

Answer (score 3):

First, experiment if possible with different types of partitioning:

`HASH,RANGE,KEY,LIST` and sub-partitioning to see which yields best results in terms of space and time.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html

Second, use `explain partitions` to get statistics on partitioning:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-info.html

Finally, I suggest looking into this very informative post:

http://chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows/